# Is it possible to get the generated version from gcloud preview app deploy?

Tags: gcloud

I've got a script that deploys and promotes a version and then tags the Git repository so that we can keep track of what code is live. Ideally the tag would match the version that was deployed for a 1:1 mapping between tag and version strings.

Is it possible to reliably get the version that was generated from within a Bash script?

Answer (score 0):

There's not an obvious way to do this right now, but you could use the `gcloud preview app modules` commands to do this in a round-about way:

```
$ gcloud preview app modules list --format='value(module,version,is_default)' |
    grep modulename |
    grep True |
    awk '{print $2}'
20150824t183552
```

The `--format` flag is there because the output isn't necessarily stable between versions. `grep True` filters for default versions.

This gives you the version number of the default version for module `modulename`, which immediately after a deployment with promotion will be the version you just created.

We have some changes to the output of `gcloud preview app deploy` that we're thinking about making, so this may get easier in the future.